# Are regions and features automatically created when creating a sub subtheme?

Tags: theming

I want to inherit everything from a main theme except the layout.
When I create the .info file and specify which regions and features I want are these generated automatically by drupal or do I have to specify each one in a separate .tpl file like the diagram below?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will enherit everything unless you modify the **page.tpl.php** file located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/template` folder.

The **page.tpl.php** file contains all **block regions**. Thus, you should modify this file if you want to add, remove, or move regions.

If you want to resize or theme a region, it's all css. As you will see in page.tpl.php, the regions will have a div `class` or `id`.